# Attach PDF to e-mail

Tags: java, pdf, attachment, itext, mime-message

What I want to do is attach one or several PDFs to an e-mail.
I am currently using `MimeMessage` to send emails which works flawlessly. The problem however is that I have no idea how to attach files. (More specifically PDFs I create using itext).

Any examples or tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [reading](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2010/11/02/how-to-create-an-in-memory-pdf-report-and-send-as-an-email-attachment-using-itext-and-java/) ("How to create an in-memory PDF report and send as an email attachment using iText and Java") should help you

Comment: http://pdfbox.apache.org/                                           Apache Java PDF Library.

Comment: @blob, please explain a bit... Article is about iText, as well as question (at least it was tagged as iText). PDFBox is alternative to iText, but how does it solve problem with attaching?

Answer (score 2):

Create an attachment on the `MimeMessage` (see javadocs), set the content type to `"application/pdf"`, get the content `OutputStream` of it and write the bytes of the PDF to it (with Apache's commons-io `IOUtils`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the famous Apache Jakart library called [Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/).

If your emails are in html format you can use this code:

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setSubject("<your subject>");
email.setHtmlMsg("<your html message body>");
email.setHostName("<host>");
email.setFrom("<from_address>");
email.addTo("<recipient_address>");
email.send();
```

and then attach your pdf files

```
EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();

String filePath = "pathtofile";
attachment.setPath(filePath);
attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
attachment.setDescription("description for this attachment");

email.attach(attachment);
```

Otherwise you should use the MultiPartEmail class.

Hope can be helpful...

ROb

Comment: where do set the content type ?? Josh.